# Mono Winforms MacOSX replacement for WebBrowser

Tags: winforms, macos, mono, webbrowser-control

I'm one step away from having my Windows .Net application working on Mac OS X, and the last thing I need to figure out is the WebBrowser control.

I need to display a webpage and not much more with winforms but haven't been able to find any examples or information on how I can replace the WebBrowser control on Mac OS X

Has anyone already found a solution for a web control replacement using winforms on mac os x, and can point me to some source code or talk me through it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently there is a way to have a Web Browser in a mono app that revolves around using Gegko/Webkit and hooking it manually into winforms, but not very well documented

Comment: Could you please show us how to do it? Maybe put a small copy-paste snippet on pastebin.com?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is any solution for embedding a webpage in a winforms app on OS X.

About the only option is to use Process.Start ("http://www.google.com"), which will launch the webpage in the user's default browser.

Comment: I have heard of people having success using Gegko/Webkit with GTK and getting it to intergrate with winforms somehow, just don't know where to start with this?

Comment: I would be interested to see that, I do not think that road leads to success.  ;)