# Mono webbrowser

Tags: web-applications, mono

I'm a new to mono enviroment and I have some question to ask...

I'm trying to make a "browser" that display me a web page,
well in windows NET is easy I can use Form.Window.WebBrowser.

So I test with Moma this app, and it notice me that I can't use Form.Window.Webbroser " mac osx not compatible",

Well I search around the web and I find this
http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/feature/14918.html
but honestly I don't understand why I should use Gdk, and glade so I try to "add reference" to *visual studio 2010* RC but I find

> Monodoc.GeckoHtmlRend

then I find an other way using Mono.WebBrowser.dll but again

> Mono.WebBrowser
>
> Mono.WebBrowser.DOM

Well my question are:

- where find documentation about one or other libs
- if I "add reference..." using menu of visual 2010 rc
  the dll linked is needed in release file or all library needed is included in release
  assembly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no implementation of the WebBrowser control on MacOSX.

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612896/mono-winforms-mac-os-x-relpacement-for-webbrowser) was posted just a few days ago.

Comment: thanks for you answer but I think that a solution could be found, I hope, and according Mono.Webbrowser.dll